# Status Of Added Places

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know that once you've added a place to Google maps, it won't come up in the autocomplete results, until it has been moderated.

I just wondered if anyone had any experience of how long this process takes?

And it is possible to see a list of your added places and whether or not they have been moderated and rejected?

Cheers

James

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of time that this will take depends on many factors. This includes available time for engineers to make the edit as well as what other updates are being added to the map.

As for seeing what places you have added and whether they have been moderated or rejected:

From maps.google.com please select the hamburger menu and then select 'your contributions.'

From there, select 'Edits'

You will be able to see any edits made from the signed in account as well as whether they have been approved or rejected.

I hope this helps!